# String not valid UTF-8 when inserting json file into mongodb

Tags: json, mongodb, utf-8

i am storing a json file produced by cucumber json report into mongodb. But i get "String not valid UTF-8” when inserting json into mongodb.

Because the feature file has 年/月/日  , this is represented as "\u5e74/\u6708/\u65e5" in the json file.
This is what i am doing to store it in mongo

```
json_string=File.read(file_path)
data = JSON.parse(json_string)
@col.insert(data)
```

I can see that after JSON.parse, the already encoded string further changes to "\x90\u0013s/\x90\u0013s/\x90\u0013s"

exception is happening at insert statement.
any help appreciated.

I tried the following but still does not work

```
json_string=File.read(file_path,:encoding => 'UTF-8')
data = JSON.parse(json_string.force_encoding("UTF-8"))
```

Using Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: Can you give us an example of the JSON file? I'm unable to reproduce this error with Ruby 1.9.3p545 and mongo gem 1.10.2.

Comment: i tried a lot to add it to my question but couldn't, here it is https://github.com/ambirag/documents/wiki/json-file-that-results-in-String-not-valid-in-utf-8-error

Comment: What does `data.encoding` return?

Comment: exception: undefined method `encoding' for #<Array:0x00000002768ed0>

Comment: Ah, that's because your JSON root is an array. Try `@col.insert(data[0])`.

Comment: i have 100s of json files and all of them are correctly inserted, only the ones that has these characters 年/月/日 or '(appostrophe) fails. I tried data[0], still fails thanks for your time

Comment: Interesting. I'm sorry I can't reproduce your issue.